# Renci SSH.NET SCP Download fails, but doesn't tell me why

Tags: c#, ssh, scp

I'm working on a program in C# which downloads a file from a remote server. I set up the connection (like I did for the upload function) like this:

```
void execute_scp_download(ScpClient scpclient, string remoteFilePath, string targetPath) {
    var downloadFilestream = File.OpenWrite(targetPath);

    try {
        scpclient.Download(remoteFilePath, downloadFilestream);
        scpclient.Disconnect();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        log_error("download could not be done: " + e);
    }
}
```

`scpclient` gets created in the calling method where I can successfully write `scpclient.Connect()` without any problems.

But when I try to download a file it'll throw an exception:

```
30.07.2020 11:08:02 Error: download could not be done: Renci.SshNet.Common.ScpException: scp: /usr/local/etc/cert.der
   at Renci.SshNet.ScpClient.ReadString(Stream stream)
   at Renci.SshNet.ScpClient.InternalDownload(IChannelSession channel, Stream input, FileSystemInfo fileSystemInfo)
   at Renci.SshNet.ScpClient.Download(String filename, FileInfo fileInfo)
   at SMGWUpdateTool.Form1.execute_scp_download(ScpClient scpclient, String remoteFilePath, String targetPath) in C:\bla\myscript.cs Line:226.
```

(I translated some of the words but none of the exception itself)

I have no clue why this doesn't work. It looks like it is an problem with the target file. The remote server is a BusyBox/Linux while my client is running on Windows 10.

Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: Scp isn't a very sophisticated protocol. There may not be any more information available than what you have. You could try performing the same file transfer with a command-line scp utility to see if it prints a better error message.

Comment: @Kenster Good idea, I will try. What I wonder about is that the exception occurred in ReadString what doesn't look like an scp problem to me.